# Can I make an exception to codeigniter autoload?

Tags: php, codeigniter

My codeigniter site autoloads sessions. I have an XML API page that I created but I'm getting a session error because of that autoload. I would prefer not to load sessions on this controller but I don't want to have to load sessions manually on all of my other controllers. Can that be done?

Comment: Could you create a base controller for all the controllers that require sessions that load the sessions and just extend that one? Then your XML API one could use a different base.

Comment: I guess I could but that would still require manual edits to all of my files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a base controller to load the session class rather than `autoload.php` and have your controllers extend it. More information here: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/core_classes.html

```
// application/core/MY_Controller.php

class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->library('session');
    }

}

// you may add additional base controller classes here
```

You must extend this controller with the ones that you want to have access to the session class, so unfortunately you will have to make some edits to your existing controllers:

```
class UserController extends MY_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        // session class is loaded
    }

}
```

Other controllers can continue to extend `CI_Controller` and the session class won't be loaded.

I use this method for all my CI projects and rarely use the `autoloader.php`, it allows much more flexibility.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but wouldn't this require me manually editing all of my existing controllers? I'm really just trying to make one single file that wouldn't be like all the others. I guess I'm trying to create an exception, not sidestep autoloading all together.

Comment: Yes, that's what it would require. There's no way around it unless you want something really hacky and dirty. It's better to take this first step and save headaches later as well, there will always be corner cases and the flexibility of this approach will pay off. Just grep your project for `extends CI_Controller {`, shouldn't take more than a few minutes to edit the files manually (the safe way). I usually have 4 or 5 different base controllers (you don't have to use "MY_Controller" for the class name).

Comment: The only other way I can think of involves editing system files; the core Loader class (the autoloader function is `private` so it can't just be extended via MY_Loader.php). Are you interested in that option? Do you have a way to identify the "exception" URLs with vanilla PHP that we can use? It won't be a nice solution, but it can be done. Once you opt in to the autoloader you can't opt out.

Comment: Thanks, I think the controller extension will be the way to go.